# pandas apply for certain row only

Tags: python, pandas

Please advise, how can I modify below code to apply to index of `p-value` only? Now it is also highlighting the index with `Mean of cases with data` which i dont want. Thanks!!

```
        def p_value_bold(val):
            bold = 'bold' if (val <= 0.05) & (val > 0) else ''
            return 'font-weight: %s' % bold
        
        def negative_yellow(val):
            color = 'yellow' if (val <= 0.05) & (val > 0) else ''
            return 'background-color:' + color 
        
    return return_df.style.applymap(p_value_bold).applymap(negative_yellow)
```

[image]

Comment: NB. your two conditions for formatting are identical, so you could combine them in a single function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you can provide a test dataset as text.

Nevertheless, can you try:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice[return_df.index.get_level_values(level=1)=='p_value', :]
return_df.style.applymap(p_value_bold, subset=idx).applymap(negative_yellow, subset=idx)
```